# Umbraco v12 - Public access on all children, including newly created, but not parent

Tags: umbraco

So I'm surprised I've not come across this anywhere, or needed to do it, but is this scenario possible?

I have a `List Page` which has  a number of `Detail Pages`.

I want anonymous users to see the list page, but when they click on the children, they will be asked to log in.

It's not quite this use-case, but imagine a summary page of article titles to spark public interest, but then you have to join the site to read the articles.

Obviously I can set public access on each child, but that'd have to be done every single time I create an article.

I can think of a couple of ways of doing this:

1. Rework the tree structure; put the child items under a separate, secured parent, then have the anonymous list page look there for titles. I have done this in the past, but it feels like it messes up the simplicity of the tree and makes it less semantic - the tree structure is now based on the security model not the content model.
2. Use a content save notification to set the public access - this feels hacky and opaque and also if the requirement changes it needs a code rebuild.

Is there a better option?

Comment: My mind immediately went to your solution 1, even though it's less than ideal. It'll probably be the easiest to implement and maintain. Solution 2 requires some behind-the-scenes "magic" that might confuse editors more than solution 1 (IMO), and it could easily end up requiring configuration or code changes for maintenance. Wish I could say I had better ideas than those two, but I don't (at least not right now :-P ).

Answer (score 0):

**Before doing anything:**
Make sure you discuss your plans with your team & client and don't make any changes before your client and your team agree on your plan. Good communication should save you and your client a lot of time and headaches.

**Option 1:**
Depending on the number of content pages, option one could work. You can have multiple folders for different types of content pages and you can set up different permissions for these different folders using the built-in ["Restrict Public Access"](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/v/10.latest-lts/tutorials/members-registration-and-login#member-only-pages-restricted-access) feature. Once the permissions are set, then the children should inherit these permissions. Once you're done with all of the necessary changes and initial setup, setting up permissions&creating content should be completely your client's responsibility.

**Option 2:**
The other option is to programmatically set the public access as you mentioned. One of the best ways for this is to use the Notification Handlers.

Below is a sample code from one of my projects for `ContentPublishedNotification`. If you go for this option, you might need to write some similar code for some of the other [ContentService Notifications, too.](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/v/10.latest-lts/reference/notifications/contentservice-notifications)

**Member Groups:**
For both options, it might be beneficial to create the Umbraco Member Groups programmatically so that you can use them later manually or from your app. If you want to do this, then the Application Startup is generally a good place to write this small piece of code that should get your Member Group names from somewhere (you should know this information) and create them in Umbraco db if they don't exist. This option is a recommended option if the member roles are created by another system, i.e. a CRM. Another option is to create them manually if they don't change very often.

You can then use the same Member Group names to set the logged-in user claims after successful login. Once the claims are set and the Umbraco content pages are protected then your users should display the restricted content page if they have the correct claims, otherwise, the built-in Restrict Public Access feature should redirect your logged-in user to a login page or an error page.

```
using Azure;
using PROJECTNAMEUmbraco.Common.Extensions;
using PROJECTNAMEUmbraco.Core.BusinessLogic.Cloudflare.CacheHandlers;
using PROJECTNAMEUmbraco.Core.BusinessLogic.Cloudflare.Helpers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Events;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Notifications;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Web;
namespace PROJECTNAMEUmbraco.Core.BusinessLogic.Cloudflare.NotificationHandlers
{
    public class ContentPublishedNotificationHandler : INotificationHandler<ContentPublishedNotification>
    {
        private readonly IUmbracoContextAccessor _umbracoContextAccessor;
        private readonly ILogger<ContentPublishedNotificationHandler> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        public ContentPublishedNotificationHandler(IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor, ILogger<ContentPublishedNotificationHandler> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _umbracoContextAccessor = umbracoContextAccessor;
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }
        public void Handle(ContentPublishedNotification notification)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_configuration.GetValue<bool>("Cloudflare:PurgeEnabled"))
                {
                    Task.Run(() => PurgeCloudflareCacheForPublishedEntities(notification)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"ContentPublishedNotificationHandler exception, ex.Message: {ex.Message}, ex.StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
        private async Task PurgeCloudflareCacheForPublishedEntities(ContentPublishedNotification notification)
        {
            var uRLs = new List<string>();
            IUmbracoContext context;
            foreach (var publishedEntity in notification.PublishedEntities)
            {
                if (_umbracoContextAccessor.TryGetUmbracoContext(out context))
                {
                    var entity = context.Content.GetById(publishedEntity.Id);
                    if (entity != null)
                    {
                        var entityUrl = Umbraco.Extensions.FriendlyPublishedContentExtensions.Url(entity);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityUrl))
                        {
                            uRLs.Add(CloudflareNotificationHelper.GetEntityUrl(entityUrl));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            var response = await CloudflareCacheHandler.PurgeCloudflareCacheByURLs(uRLs, _httpClientFactory);
            _logger.LogInformation($"ContentPublishedNotificationHandler PurgeCloudflareCacheByURLs has been called called for {string.Join(' ', uRLs)}, responseJSON: {response.CloudflareResponseJSON}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Details:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]